# Raspbian G++ 8.3.0 using lambda expression causes Expected primary expression before ']' - even though standard is set to c++14

Tags: c++

I'm currently working on a C++ project on my Raspberry Pi.
I'm using the latest Raspbian version and have the G++ toolchain installed (8.3.0 armhf).

When cross-compiling the same code via my PC, everything works just fine and I can even execute test code using the folowing functions on my Pi.
When compiling on my Pi however, the compiler refuses to build my project.

The error is

> Extensions.hpp:65:75: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token

The line in question is as follows:

```
transform(mixedCase.begin(), mixedCase.end(), mixedCase.begin() [&](uint8_t _char) { return tolower(_char); });
                                                                 ^ error occurs here
```

Which itself is in an inline function.
This is the exact compiler version I'm using:

> c++ (Raspbian 8.3.0-6+rpi1) 8.3.0
>   Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>   This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
>   warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

I'm building using CMake and a Makefile, both produce the exact same error message.
Here's the CMake config for standard use:

```
###
# Set language version
###
set(CMAKE_CXX_VERSION 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED True)
# Enable GNU extensions
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS ON)
```

Is using lambdas when compiling on the Raspi not supported for some reason?
Is there another way around this, except relying on a function object?

Comment: Comma before lambda is missing, the lambda is another argument

Answer (score 1):

Transform takes four arguments, you forgot one comma before your lambda.

Comment: Ah jeez. Thanks for pointing that one out. 
That's what I get for using nano.

Voted for close.